# How to disable a submit button and show div if an inputs first 3 characters has value of "xyz"

Tags: regex, angular, forms

Disable submit button and show DIV if person enters the characters "59-"

The problem I have is it's easy to do if the only characters typed are "59-" but if you type "59-xyz" or anything after the dash it then enables the button and hides the div.

Using ngModel on the input I can get the value but I am trying to do a compare using a regex of /^59-/ but it complains due to comparing a string and a boolean.

public accountId: any;
public regEx = /^59-/.test(this.accountId);

Comment: Starts with: "/^xyz.*$/"

Comment: Contains: "(?s).*\\xyz\\b.*"

Answer (score 1):

Your regex seems to be fine. Your error is probably because you have assigned a boolean to `regEx` here `public regEx = /^59-/.test(this.accountId);` and tried to compare that to a string.

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-regex-pattern-validation) on how to do this using both reactive forms and template driven forms (`ngModel`).